# Xcode 14 - Cannot preview in this file, Cannot connect to iPhone 14 | FailedToConnectToDTServiceHubError: Cannot connect to iPhone 14

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, xcode14, swiftui-previews

while exploring the swiftUI and creating my first swiftUI app in Xcode, it is throwing an error for the preview saying - Cannot preview in this file, Cannot connect to [Device Name]. **While it's working fine in simulator**.

In order to troubleshoot, I've already tried all the basic hacks like -

- Deleting the DerivedData,
- Uncheck Automatically Refresh Canvas [As suggested in some stackOverflow answers],
- Rebooting the mac[Intel Based]/device,
- Updating the latest macOS [currently it's 12.5.1],
- [Removing the Xcode completely](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-from-mac),
- Installing the latest Xcode from scratch [Currently it's Xcode v14.0],
- Tried removing all the simulators and installing a fresh one.

On the stackOverflow, there are few similar questions asked, but the reason is different after the title "Cannot preview in this file ..... "

attaching the screenshot of newly created test project >>

[image: Preview Error]
[image: Preview Diagnostic Description]

Please suggest with any solution which can help to resolve the issue,
Thanks in advance

Comment: After trying almost everything (which didn't help me of-course) I format my machine and fresh install Xcode worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Just **quit** Xcode and reopen. On the top of Xcode you will see loading animation like "*Preparing simulator for Previews*". After that your preview will work

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this issue with Xcode 14.2, really frustrating. Resolved by uninstalling Xcode completely and reinstalling from app store. Currently running Xcode 14.3.1 and previews work just fine.